# Mongodb Sequential Schema Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Victim schema :

```
let Victim= new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    gender: {type: String},
    Id: {type: String},
    address: {type: String},    
});
```

a Culprit schema :

```
let Culprit= new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    gender: {type: String},
    cellphone: {type: String},
    address: {type: String},    
});
```

and a Case Schema :

```
let Case= new Schema({
    victims:[String],//this contains array of victims _id's
    culprits:[String],//this contains array of culprit _id's
    aboutCase:{type:String},
    caseType:{type:String}, 
    date:{type:String}
})
```

Take note that the victims field of the Case schema contains _id's of victims, while the culprits fields contains the _id's of culprits, both as arrays.

Now if i do this :

```
Case.find(function(err, allTheCases) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(allTheCases);
//Question : How to get victims and culprits data as complete objects instead of just array of _id's
        }
    });
```

the result, `allTheCases` is an array of all Case objects, in which each object contains victims field. This victims fields contains array of victims _id's.

My question is : what is the correct query syntax so the final result (`allTheCases`) will have the complete array of Victims and Culprits objects instead of just array of _id's of victims and culprits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup) in mongodb aggregation pipeline

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

Or, if you are using Mongoose ODM you can [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) necessary fields with corresponding method:

```
let Case= new Schema({
victims:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Victim' }],
culprits:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Culprits'}],
aboutCase:{type:String},
caseType:{type:String}, 
date:{type:String}})
```

And when query:

```
Case.find().
     populate('victims').
     populate('culprits').
     exec(function (err, cases) {

      });
```

Comment: just a little bit of typo : you have unnecessary curly bracket in Case schema here : `victims:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Victim' }}]` . If you'll just fix it, the answer will be perfect.

Comment: Sure, did not noticed